# How to let mouse wheel scrolling not change system settings?

Tags: mouse, settings

If mouse pointer hanged over a system setting bar and you accidentally scrolled its wheel, the value of the setting was changed. And due to the fact that many of the settings will take effect immediately after its value being changed, you may have obliviously changed something. Sometimes you noticed that the setting value was accidentally changed, but you can't change it back because you didn't know its initial "correct" value before the change was done.

Thus, I'm wondering: is there any way to not let this happen? For example, disable mouse wheel scrolling when the pointer just hangs over a setting?

Comment: YES! Why didn't this get an answer in all those years? This behavior is so annoying! It should be a setting, or something that only happens while you hold something, like ALT+SCROLL.